# Where to find book sugestions?

Tags: website, ebook, last.fm

I would like to know if any site or app can help me find books I would like, based on the books I read.

I am looking for something similar to last.fm or grooveshark.com, but for books.

Comment: Wow, a template question. Just add the thing you're looking for ;-)

Comment: Anyways, try Glue (I know, it's a silly name) for Firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3481?src=api

Comment: @Idigas I really like Glue, but I think it should have separate suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like...Amazon? half.com? border.com? barnesandnoble.com? they all have recommendation systems